# Custom Control does not appear when running application on other machine

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, custom-controls

I have designed a radio button custom control. it works fine on my computer but when i port my application on th other machine that doesn't appear.

any body does know why?

here is part of my control:

```
public class CustomCheckBox:UserControl
{
    public CustomCheckBox()
    {
     // Height+=50;
      count++;
      index = count;
      Height = 50;
      Width = 100;
      Region r = new Region(new Rectangle( 0, 0, Width, Height));
      this.Region = r;

      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);


    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            // cp.Style &= ~0x02000000;
            return cp;
        }
    } 
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        paintState = 0;            
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
  ...
```

Comment: The WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag is only valid on toplevel windows, not controls.  Attribution is required here btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved as [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) has commented above, i removed the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag which was used to apply drawing optimization to remove flicker on appearance and instead i used this kind of optimization in constructor and it worked fine.

```
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.CacheText, true);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, false);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedHeight, true);
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedWidth, true);
```